# Java Linked List - can't access data if its been viewed already

Tags: java, linked-list

Calling this function once works well and prints out all the contents of the Linked List I created. However, if I call it more than once, then it only prints the value of the head(line 2) from the next time it's called. Why is this? I am new to programming so any help would be much appreciated! Is there a way for me to test to find out the cause of the error?

```
    public void printLinkedList(Node head) {
        System.out.println("test: " + head.next.data);

        Node n = head;
        System.out.println("value: " + n.data);

        while(n.next !=null) {
            System.out.println("value: " + n.next.data);
            n.next = n.next.next;
            //n = n.next;

        }

    }
```

Comment: Your print method should make no changes on the list, so you should not reassign values of your Nodes like you do in `n.next = n.next.next;`

Comment: Thank you, thank solved it!

Answer (score 0):

Solution from from comments above:

```
    public void printLinkedList(Node head) {
        System.out.println("test: " + head.next.data);

        Node n = head;
        System.out.println("value: " + n.data);

        while(n.next !=null) {
            System.out.println("value: " + n.data);
            //n.next = n.next.next;
            n = n.next;        
        }

    }
```